# Assigning values in a sequence to a group of consecutive rows leaving some rows empty

Tags: r, conditional-statements, sequence, rows

I'm trying to group several consecutives rows (and assigning them the same value) while leaving some of the rows empty (when a certain condition is not fulfilled).

My data are locations (xy coordinates), the date/time at which they were measured, and the time span between measures. Somehow simplified, they look like this:

```
ID   X     Y      Time    Span
1    3445  7671   0:00    -
2    3312  7677   4:00    4
3    3309  7680   12:00   8
4    3299  7681   16:00   4
5    3243  7655   20:00   4
6    3222  7612   4:00    8
7    3260  7633   0:00    4
8    3254  7641   8:00    8
9    3230  7612   0:00    16
10   3203  7656   4:00    4
11   3202  7678   8:00    4
12   3159  7609   20:00   12
...
```

I'd like to assign a value to every sequence of locations that are measured within a time span of 4 hours, and make my data look like this:

```
ID   X     Y      Time    Span  Sequence
1    3445  7671   0:00    -     -
2    3312  7677   4:00    4     1
3    3309  7680   12:00   8     NA
4    3299  7681   16:00   4     2
5    3243  7655   20:00   4     2
6    3222  7612   4:00    8     NA
7    3260  7633   0:00    4     3
8    3254  7641   8:00    8     NA
9    3230  7612   0:00    16    NA
10   3203  7656   4:00    4     4
11   3202  7678   8:00    4     4
12   3159  7609   20:00   12    NA
```

I've tried several algorithms with a loop "for" plus "ifelse" condition like:

```
Sequence <- for (i in 1:max(ID)) {
ifelse (Span <= 4, i+1, "NA")
}
```

without any luck. I know my attempt is incorrect, but my programming skills are really basic and I haven't found any similar problem in the web.

Any ideas would be very appreciated!

Comment: Your pseudo code says that if `Span <= 4, `Sequence` should be `i+1` where `i` is the row number. However, in your desired output you have multiple rows with the same `Sequence` value? (for example two rows with `Sequence` 2). So, how do you want to assign `Sequence` values to rows?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a longish one liner:

```
ifelse(x <- DF$Span == 4, cumsum(c(head(x, 1), tail(x, -1) - head(x, -1) == 1)), NA)
# [1] NA  1 NA  2  2 NA  3 NA NA  4  4 NA
```

Explanation:

- `x` is a vector of TRUE/FALSE showing where `Span` is `4`.
- `tail(x, -1)` is a safe way of writing `x[2:length(x)]`
- `head(x, -1)` is a safe way of writing `x[1:(length(x)-1)]`
- `tail(x, -1) - head(x, -1) == 1` is a vector of TRUE/FALSE showing where we went from `Span != 4` to `Span == 4`.
- since the vector above is one element shorter than `x`, I prepended `head(x, 1)` in front of it. `head(x, 1)` is a safe way of writing `x[1]`.
- Then I take the `cumsum` so it converts the vector TRUE/FALSE into a vector of increasing integers: where `Span` jumps from `!=4` to `==4` it increases by 1, otherwise stays constant.
- Everything is wrapped into an `ifelse` so you only see numbers where `x` is TRUE, i.e., where `Span == 4`.

Comment: @flodel, Can you expand just a little bit on your answer explaining the logic of what you're doing. It might make your answer more searchable and thus more useful for others with a similar problem in the future.

Comment: @mrdwab, only because you asked! Otherwise I think it takes a bit of the magic away :-)

Comment: @flodel, with your elaboration, how can I resist giving you a +1. I had worked through your magic by running each nested piece, but thought it would be good to have an explained answer since I hadn't actually ever seen `head` and `tail` used that way.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another alternative using `rle` and `rep`. We'll assume that your `data.frame` is named "test".

First, initialize your "Sequence" column, filling it with `NA`.

```
test$Sequence <- NA
```

Second, specify the condition that you are matching, in this case, `test$Span == 4`.

```
x <- test$Span == 4
```

Third, use the combination of `rle`'s output (`lengths` and `values`) to get how many times each new run in the sequence occurs.

```
spanSeq <- rle(x)$lengths[rle(x)$values == TRUE]
```

Finally, use `rep` with the `times` argument set to the result obtained in step 3. Subset the required values of `test$Sequence` according to the index matched by `test$Span == 4`, and replace them with your new sequence.

```
test$Sequence[x] <- rep(seq_along(spanSeq), times = spanSeq)
test
#    ID    X    Y  Time Span Sequence
# 1   1 3445 7671  0:00    -       NA
# 2   2 3312 7677  4:00    4        1
# 3   3 3309 7680 12:00    8       NA
# 4   4 3299 7681 16:00    4        2
# 5   5 3243 7655 20:00    4        2
# 6   6 3222 7612  4:00    8       NA
# 7   7 3260 7633  0:00    4        3
# 8   8 3254 7641  8:00    8       NA
# 9   9 3230 7612  0:00   16       NA
# 10 10 3203 7656  4:00    4        4
# 11 11 3202 7678  8:00    4        4
# 12 12 3159 7609 20:00   12       NA
```

---

Once you understand the steps involved, you can also do this directly with `within()`. The following would give you the same result:

```
within(test, {
  Sequence <- NA
  spanSeq <- rle(Span == 4)$lengths[rle(Span == 4)$values == TRUE]
  Sequence[Span == 4] <- rep(seq_along(spanSeq), times = spanSeq)
  rm(spanSeq)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
for (i in 1:max(ID)) {
      Sequence[i] = ifelse(Span[i] <= 4, count <- count+1, NA)
}
```

Comment: This assigns the string `"NA"` not the value `NA`. Also, `ifelse` is vectorised so you're better off using `my_df$Sequence <- ifelse(my_df$Span <= 4, (1:max(my_df$ID))+1, NA)` which is equivalent to the code you've written. However all this is moot as `count + 1` appears *not* to be what the OP wants to put into the `Sequence` column.