# Grouping rows on the basis of row differences in R

Tags: r, grouping

I have a set of animal locations with different sampling intervals. What I want to do is group and seqences where the sampling interval matches a certain criteria (e.g. is below a certain value). Let me illustrate with some dummy data:

```
start <- Sys.time()
timediff <- c(rep(5,3),20,rep(5,2))
timediff <- cumsum(timediff)

# Set up a dataframe with a couple of time values
df <- data.frame(TimeDate = start + timediff)

# Calculate the time differences between the rows
df$TimeDiff <- c(as.integer(tail(df$TimeDate,-1) - head(df$TimeDate,-1)),NA)

# Define a criteria in order to form groups
df$TimeDiffSmall <- df$TimeDiff <= 5

             TimeDate TimeDiff TimeDiffSmall
1 2016-03-15 23:11:49        5          TRUE
2 2016-03-15 23:11:54        5          TRUE
3 2016-03-15 23:11:59       20         FALSE
4 2016-03-15 23:12:19        5          TRUE
5 2016-03-15 23:12:24        5          TRUE
6 2016-03-15 23:12:29       NA            NA
```

In this dummy data, rows 1:3 belong to one group, since the time difference between them is <= 5 seconds. 4 - 6 belong to the second group, but hypothetically there could be a number of rows in between the two groups that dont belong to any group (`TimeDiffSmall` equals to `FALSE`).

Combining the information from two multiple SO answers (e.g. [part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12984511/4139249)), I've create a function that solves this problem.

```
number.groups <- function(input){
  # part 1: numbering successive TRUE values
  input[is.na(input)] <- F
  x.gr <- ifelse(x <- input == TRUE, cumsum(c(head(x, 1), tail(x, -1) - head(x, -1) == 1)),NA)
  # part 2: including last value into group
  items <- which(!is.na(x.gr))
  items.plus <- c(1,items+1)
  sel <- !(items.plus %in% items)
  sel.idx <- items.plus[sel]
  x.gr[sel.idx] <- x.gr[sel.idx-1]
  return(x.gr)


 # Apply the function to create groups
 df$Group <- number.groups(df$TimeDiffSmall)

             TimeDate TimeDiff TimeDiffSmall Group
1 2016-03-15 23:11:49        5          TRUE     1
2 2016-03-15 23:11:54        5          TRUE     1
3 2016-03-15 23:11:59       20         FALSE     1
4 2016-03-15 23:12:19        5          TRUE     2
5 2016-03-15 23:12:24        5          TRUE     2
6 2016-03-15 23:12:29       NA            NA     2
```

This function actually works to solve my problem. This this is, it seems like a crazy and rookie way to go about this. Is there a function that could solve my problem more professionally?

Comment: Does `cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(df$TimeDate) > 5))` do it for your larger example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @thelatemail, I'd use the following to get the group IDs. It works because `cumsum()` will end up incrementing the group count each time it reaches an element preceded by a greater-than-5-second time interval.

```
df$Group <- cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(df$TimeDate) > 5))
df$Group
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

Comment: Or `cumsum(c(FALSE,!(diff(df$TimeDate) <= 5)))` if you want to keep framing the selection in the way it is, rather than the way it isn't.

Comment: @thelatemail That's what I started out with actually, and when I saw I'd then need to add one to  the result (or change the initial `FALSE` to a `TRUE`) to get group numbers starting with one, I flipped it all around to what seems the simpler incantation.

Comment: Fair enough - it depends I suppose if the selection criteria is complex. Then negating it is easier than trying to reverse it all manually and ensuring the `&`'s and `|`'s all are correct.

Comment: @thelatemail You're right. Looking back at times I've used it in the past (e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171203/cumulative-sums-over-run-lengths-can-this-loop-be-vectorized/8171651#8171651)), it looks like that's what I've more often ended up using, and I think you've just identified why that's so.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for the duplicate post. Now that the discussion is running, let me adress a small issue I have with your answer (although I'm blown away by the beauty of its simplicity): If I have a timelag of > 5 seconds between the rows, I would want those values to belong to no group (NA). I've slightly updated my dummy data to address this point. Using your function, rows 4 and 5 now belong to their own group (2 and 3). Is there a way so elegantly solve this problem?

Comment: Hi. If you haven't yet figured that out, I'd suggest asking that as a new question that makes reference back to this one, while reverting this question back to its previous state. Cheers.

Comment: ok, just did as you suggested. Here's the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36039026/4139249