# Classify column values into new column with specific output

Tags: r, classification, row

I want to classify the rows of a data frame based on a threshold applied to a given numeric reference column. If the reference column has a value below the threshold, then the result is 0, which I want to add to a new column. If the reference column value is over the threshold, then the new column will have value 1 in all consecutive rows with value over the threshold until a new 0 result comes up. If a new reference value is over the threshold then the value to add is 2, and so on.

If we set up the threshold > 2 then an example of what I would like to obtain is:

| row | reference | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 |
| 6 | 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 8 | 2 |
| 8 | 4 | 2 |
| 9 | 1 | 0 |
| 10 | 3 | 3 |
| 11 | 6 | 3 |

```
row <- c(1:11)
reference <- c(2,1,4,3,1,6,8,4,1,3,6)
result <- c(0,0,1,1,0,2,2,2,0,3,3)
table <- cbind(row, reference, result)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a data frame or a matrix? Your example is a matrix. Also, note that `table` is a function in base R. You should avoid naming objects the same as existing functions

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, you are right, I forgot to add a capital T, but in any case, this was just an example to illustrate what I need to do with a huge data frame I have.

Answer (score 2):

We can use run-length encoding (rle) for this.

The below assumes a `data.frame`:

```r
r <- rle(quux$reference <= 2)
r$values <- ifelse(r$values, 0, cumsum(r$values))
quux$result2 <- inverse.rle(r)
quux
#    row reference result result2
# 1    1         2      0       0
# 2    2         1      0       0
# 3    3         4      1       1
# 4    4         3      1       1
# 5    5         1      0       0
# 6    6         6      2       2
# 7    7         8      2       2
# 8    8         4      2       2
# 9    9         1      0       0
# 10  10         3      3       3
# 11  11         6      3       3
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(row = 1:11, reference = c(2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 6, 8, 4, 1, 3, 6), result = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments by @Sotos, would consider alternative name for your object.

Since it wasn't clear if data.frame or matrix, assume we have a data.frame `df` based on your data:

```
df <- as.data.frame(table)
```

And have a threshold of 2:

```
threshold = 2
```

You can adapt [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12984511/3460670) by @flodel:

```
df$new_result = ifelse(
  x <- reference > threshold, 
  cumsum(c(x[1], diff(x) == 1)), 
  0)
df
```

In this case, the `diff(x)` will include a vector, where values of 1 indicate where result should be increased by `cumsum` (in the sample data, this occurs in rows 3, 6, and 10). These are transitions from FALSE to TRUE (0 to 1), where `reference` goes from below to above `threshold`. Note that `x[1]` is added/combined since the `diff` values will be 1 element shorter in length.

Using the `ifelse`, these new incremental values only apply to those where `reference` exceeds `threshold`, otherwise set at 0.

**Output**

```
   row reference result new_result
1    1         2      0          0
2    2         1      0          0
3    3         4      1          1
4    4         3      1          1
5    5         1      0          0
6    6         6      2          2
7    7         8      2          2
8    8         4      2          2
9    9         1      0          0
10  10         3      3          3
11  11         6      3          3
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked out well for my dataset.